# Converting parralel CUDA program to run sequentially

Tags: c++, cuda, image-manipulation, sequential

I have the following CUDA program which converts an image from RGBA into greyscale in parallel. I want to also have a version which will run sequentially which will allow me to compare the two and get metrics like speedup etc.

From my understanding, in order for this to run sequentially I need to edit in a way that will mean the image is stepped through pixel by pixel using two for loops (one for X, one for Y). The greyscale conversion should then be run on the pixel before moving onto the next one.

Whilst I have some idea of what I should be doing I'm not really sure where I should be editing the code and where to get started.

Edit: I now understand that it is the kernel itself I need to be editing in order to make my program sequential.

Shown below,

```
 __global__ void colorConvert(unsigned char * grayImage, unsigned char * rgbImage, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
{
    unsigned int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    //unsigned int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y; //this is needed if you use 2D grid and blocks
    //if ((x < width) && (y < height)) {
    //check if out of bounds
    if ((x < width*height)) {
        // get 1D coordinate for the grayscale image
        unsigned int grayOffset = x;// y*width + x; //this is needed if you use 2D grid and blocks
        // one can think of the RGB image having
        // CHANNEL times columns than the gray scale image
        unsigned int rgbOffset = grayOffset*CHANNELS;
        unsigned char r = rgbImage[rgbOffset]; // red value for pixel
        unsigned char g = rgbImage[rgbOffset + 1]; // green value for pixel
        unsigned char b = rgbImage[rgbOffset + 2]; // blue value for pixel
        // perform the rescaling and store it
        // We multiply by floating point constants
        grayImage[grayOffset] = 0.21f*r + 0.71f*g + 0.07f*b;
    }
}
```

I have removed the rest of my code from the question as there was a lot of it too look through. If I want to make this kernel run in a sequential way using two for loops to step through each pixel and apply the `grayImage[grayOffset]` line of code to each one how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a for loop, with your code you use a 1D array for all the image pixels so you need only one for.

I think that the loop can be written like that, in a function that takes the same parameters as your kernel

```
for(x=0; x<width*height; ++x)
{
    unsigned int grayOffset = x;
    unsigned int rgbOffset = grayOffset*CHANNELS;
    unsigned char r = rgbImage[rgbOffset]; // red value for pixel
    unsigned char g = rgbImage[rgbOffset + 1]; // green value for pixel
    unsigned char b = rgbImage[rgbOffset + 2]; // blue value for pixel
    // perform the rescaling and store it
    // We multiply by floating point constants
    grayImage[grayOffset] = 0.21f*r + 0.71f*g + 0.07f*b;

}
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou very much! It was the x<width*height that I was having trouble figuring out and was trying to use two for loops. I've managed to get this running in my code now so much appreciated.

Comment: In your kernel you see your image like a 1D picture so you can do the same with your CPU code.  In this case you didn't need infrmation with the pixel around the pixel that your convert so see the picture like a 1D-array is more easy